# Adding json data to a listview

Tags: c#, android, json, listview, xamarin.android

I am trying to add data to my listview using json data returned by an api, I have a class with the structure of the list, however when i try and add the data in using a for loop its fails and doesn't add it in, it tries to run the loop once then exits the loop. On expecting the list it has a count of 0.

ListAvivity.cs

```
dynamic mFarms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

List<MyList.Data> mItems = new List<FarmsList.Data>();

foreach(var items in mFarms.data)
{
  mItems.Add(new MyList.Data() {FarmID = items["FarmID"].ToString(), FarmerSurname = items["FarmerSurname"].ToString(), 
                FarmerForename = items["FarmerForename"].ToString(), FarmName = items["FarmName"].ToString()});
}
```

MyList.cs

```
public class MyList
{
    public class Data
    {
        public int FarmID { get; set; }
        public string FarmName { get; set; }
        public string FarmerSurname { get; set; }
        public string FarmerForename { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Json Data

```
{
"code": 201,
"status": "Success",
"message": "Object found",
"data": [
    {
        "FarmID": 1,
        "FarmName": "Test1",
        "FarmerSurname": "Test",
        "FarmerForename": "Test"
    },
    {
        "FarmID": 2,
        "FarmName": "Test2",
        "FarmerSurname": "Test",
        "FarmerForename": "Test"
    }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: `its fails and doesn't add it in.` - So what does happen? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: nothing it tries once and then skips it

Comment: The example you've shown works fine for me, it loops twice as expected and reads the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The program didn't enter the loop because you couldn't deserialize the json object. I suggest you to deserialize it as a known type instead of `dynamic`.

Create json classes;

```
public class Datum
{
    public int FarmID { get; set; }
    public string FarmName { get; set; }
    public string FarmerSurname { get; set; }
    public string FarmerForename { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it;

```
var mFarms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Content>(content);
List<MyList.Data> mItems = new List<FarmsList.Data>();

foreach(var items in mFarms.data)
{
  mItems.Add(new MyList.Data() {FarmID = items["FarmID"].ToString(), FarmerSurname = items["FarmerSurname"].ToString(), 
                FarmerForename = items["FarmerForename"].ToString(), FarmName = items["FarmName"].ToString()});
}
```

Also, to print `mItems`, build a loop;

```
foreach (var mitem in mItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mitem.FarmID);
    Console.WriteLine(mitem.FarmerSurname);
    //etc
}
```

Comment: The provided JSON absolutely deserializes into a `dynamic` type and the loop works fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried it there is no problem with dynamic. But as I said it could be better to use a known type.

Comment: Yes, that is ideal, but it doesn't answer the question as the issue wasn't to do with whether OP deserialized into dynamic or a class anyway.

Comment: the app crashes when it tries to add the item into the list

Comment: What is the error ? Would you provide it in detail ?

Comment: there is no error it just crashes, the last line in the code is a simple `Console.WriteLine(mItems)` but it doesn't get to that

Comment: Try to iterate loop to print the mItems list.

Comment: I just tried stepping through the loop it doesn't get passed adding in the items, it fails on that line with no error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161324/discussion-between-rainman-and-gurpreet-bhopal).